# SVG Animation issue (svg blurring while zooming)

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've created a SVG image, but when I tried to animate the container the **svg image seems pixelated during the animation** and becomes fine as soon as the animation finishes,

The code that i used for animation,

```
var nContainer = document.getElementById('container');
function zoom () {
  nContainer.style.transform = 'scale(10)';
}

function reset () {
  nContainer.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
}
```

You can find the full source code from the following url,
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEazOX

Is there any kind of fixes or alternative methods for fixing the pixelation issue?

Comment: It presumably has something to do with upscaling. By adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to your `#container`, like I did [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emdwBd), you can see when zooming out you do not have the blurring anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Just to confirm: Are you using Chrome in your testing? Because Firefox gets the zooming right without blurring the vector shape. So I think this is a Chrome only behavior.

Initially I thought about promoting the layer to the GPU directly (setting `will-change` property or a `translate3d`) could help but it doesn’t. I also tried to not set the scaling on the container but the SVG itself which doesn’t help either.

**But I’ve found another solution:** Create a wrapper around the shape inside the SVG element. It seems this works and does’t make it blurry. Of course you then need to scale the container accordingly in a separate way. In my tests this worked: http://codepen.io/anselmh/pen/qEazRV

Please see line 3+4 in HTML/SVG code, line 12 in CSS and JS.

Comment: Thanks it seems working in the given example, but in my real scenario I've several SVG files (external files). And we want to scale all those images together that's why i'm scaling the container :(

Comment: Hm, I’ve also found several WebKit bugs confirming the given behavior, all unresolved regarding your issue.

Comment: But of course you can inject the `<g>` by JavaScript and still use my solution. It’s a workaround but if you care about Chrome rendering I think that’s the only way to go.